# How to navigate to the previous route on paper-button click?

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I have used **`lit-element-router`** and was trying to navigate to the previous route on button click.

```
<paper-button @click="${() => this.goBack()}">Go back</paper-button>

goBack() {
  this.navigate();
}
```

**Question**: How to get the previous route path on clicking the button?

Any solution would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/hamedasemi/lit-element-router/blob/mainline/lit-element-router.js) then you can see that the `navigate` function uses window.history under the hood.

This will work:

```
<paper-button @click="${() => window.history.back()}">Go Back</paper-button>
```